# How do I make the users answers to the questions not case sensitive?

Tags: html, xcode, symbols, case-sensitive

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en"> 
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
charset=iso-8859-1"> 
   <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Mozilla/4.51 (Macintosh; I; PPC) 
[Netscape]"> 
   <title>Correcting cloze exercise</title> 
<script LANGUAGE="javascript">
function Gradeit() 
{

function getvalues(){

return document.quiz.q1.value 
return document.quiz.q2.value 
return document.quiz.q3.value 
return document.quiz.q4.value 
return document.quiz.q5.value 
return document.quiz.q6.value 
return document.quiz.q7.value 
return document.quiz.q8.value 
return document.quiz.q9.value 
return document.quiz.q10.value 
} 




var Answers=new Array(10) 
Answers[0]="Rawls" 
Answers[1]="Utilitarianism" 
Answers[2]="Deontological" 
Answers[3]="Socialist" 
Answers[4]="Contractual" 
Answers[5]="Veil of Ignorance" 
Answers[6]="Stage 2" 
Answers[7]="Intent based Utilitarianism" 
Answers[8]="Libertarian Justice" 
Answers[9]="Kant" 


var UserAnswers = new Array(10) 
UserAnswers[0] = document.quiz.q1.value 
UserAnswers[1] = document.quiz.q2.value 
UserAnswers[2] = document.quiz.q3.value 
UserAnswers[3] = document.quiz.q4.value 
UserAnswers[4] = document.quiz.q5.value 
UserAnswers[5] = document.quiz.q6.value 
UserAnswers[6] = document.quiz.q7.value 
UserAnswers[7] = document.quiz.q8.value 
UserAnswers[8] = document.quiz.q9.value 
UserAnswers[9] = document.quiz.q10.value 


var count0 = 0 
document.quiz.number_correct.value = 0 


if (Answers[0] == UserAnswers[0]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox1.value=""} 
else
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox1.value="X"}

if (Answers[1] == UserAnswers[1]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox2.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox2.value="X"}

if (Answers[2] == UserAnswers[2]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox3.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox3.value="X"}

if (Answers[3] == UserAnswers[3]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox4.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox4.value="X"}

if (Answers[4] == UserAnswers[4]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox5.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox5.value="X"}

if (Answers[5] == UserAnswers[5]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox6.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox6.value="X"}

if (Answers[6] == UserAnswers[6]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox7.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox7.value="X"}

if (Answers[7] == UserAnswers[7]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox8.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox8.value="X"}

if (Answers[8] == UserAnswers[8]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox9.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox9.value="X"}

if (Answers[9] == UserAnswers[9]) 
 {count0 = count0 + 1, document.quiz.ebox10.value=" "} 
else 
 {count0 = count0, document.quiz.ebox10.value="X"}

document.quiz.number_correct.value = count0 


 }

</script> 
</head> 
<body>

<h1> 
Self-Correcting and Grading Fill-ins</h1> 

<p>Directions.&nbsp; Fill in the blanks in the sentences below with the 
appropriate vocabulary words from the box below.&nbsp; Note there are 
five 
extra words.&nbsp; After filling it in, click the "Grade it" button. The button "Get answer key" opens a new 
window, 
where all the answers are listed.
<br>&nbsp; 
<center><table COLS=3 WIDTH="75%" > 
<tr> 
<td>Principle of Equal Liberty Rights</td>

<td>Intent based Utilitarianism</td>

<td>Capitalist</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td>Stage 2</td>

<td>Contractual</td>

<td>Rawls</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td>Deontological</td>

<td>Legal</td>

<td>Universalizable</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td>Veil of Ignorance</td>

<td>Utilitarianism</td>

<td>Libertarian Justice</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td>Stage 3</td>

<td>Kant</td>

<td>Socialist</td> </tr>


<td>&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
</table></center>

<p><form NAME="quiz"><input name="ebox1" type="text" size="1"><b>#1: Which writer was a major proponent of the theory of Justice as Fairness?</b><input name="q1" type="text" size="25">

<p><input name="ebox2" type="text" size="1"><b>#2: A decision focused on outcome or consequences that emphasizes the greatest good for the greatest number&nbsp;</b><input name="q2" type="text" size="25">

<p><input name="ebox3" type="text" size="1"><b>#3: An approach that focuses on “universal ethical principles”

&nbsp;<input name="q3" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox4" type="text" size="1"><b>#4: Which justice is criticised for providing a disincentive to contribute, since we’ll all get the same benefits no matter what (free rider problem)?
 &nbsp;<input 
name="q4" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox5" type="text" size="1"><b>#5 Limited rights and duties that arise when individuals enter into agreements with one another.
<input 
name="q5" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox6" type="text" size="1"><b>#6 The point of this is to remove personal bias from the choice of principles. 
  &nbsp;<input name="q6" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox7" type="text" size="1"><b>#7 Reason for doing the right thing is to gain rewards (i.e., right actions are “instruments” for satisfying one’s own needs) is which stage of the Moral Cognitive Development Model?
<input 
name="q7" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox8" type="text" size="1"><b>#8  If you genuinely tried your best to maximize utility, you’ve done the right thing, even if it turns out in the end that utility wasn’t maximized is  
&nbsp;<input name="q8" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox9" type="text" size="1"><b>#9:The people who have them, earn them, or are freely given them describes which justice?
 <input 
name="q9" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input name="ebox10" type="text" size="1"><b>#10: Reversible, universalizable
and treating stakeholders as an end unto themselves and does not use them only as a means to an end is part of which theory? 
 <input name="q10" type="text" size="25"></b>

<p><input TYPE="button" VALUE="Grade Me" onClick="Gradeit()"><input 
type="reset" Value="Clear All Answers"><br>

<b>You got&nbsp;<input name="number_correct" type="text" 
size="4">correct out of 10. Try questions marked with the "X" again, and click the button to have your answers checked again.</b> 
</form> 
</body> enter code here
</html>
```

Apart from making the users answers not case sensitive, any idea on how to put a green tick mark when a user has a correct answer? Currently it is blank if the user is right. So I need something that shows a green tick mark for right answers and a red cross for wrong answers.

Answer (score 1):

I Javascript you can convert any string to lowercase with

```
"string".toLowerCase()
```

Or in the case of a variable:

```
variable.toLowerCase()
```

This method makes it much easier to do comparisons since the letters will become all lowercase. I hope that's what you were asking. Green tick marks as you also wanted to know resolve around adding/removing content from the document object model. One way is to display an image and then change the source of the image to either a check or "x" mark based on the answer. For instance:

```
if(true) { //if the answer is correct
    document.getElementById('image').src = 'check.png';
} else {
    document.getElementById('image').src = 'wrong.png';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To incorporate Gwiddle's answer, you would need to have an image next to each answer, it wherever you want it to be. However, you should initially give it no source, and give it an id of "markbox0" or similar

```
<img src="" id="markbox0" alt="mark">
```

You will now be able to change the source of the image laster in the code as shown by Gwiddle by using

```
 document.getElementById('markbox').src = 'check.png';
```

Also, as a general coding tip, if you are performing a similar set of code for a long list of items, it is often far easier to use a loop rather than writing out every single one. This would be especially useful if you wanted to add more questions to your page. A simple 'for' loop will save lots of space and writing. In this, you use a variable which counts up each time the loop code runs, allowing you to step through a long list of things. For example, your answer checking code could be achieved with:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Answers.length; i = i + 1){
    if (Answers[i] == UserAnswers[i]) 
        {count0 = count0 + 1;
        document.getElementById('markbox' + String(i)).src = 'check.png';} 
    else
        {count0 = count0;
        document.getElementById('markbox' + String(i)).src = 'cross.png';}
}
```

This loop runs the code with 'i' as the number, for the number of times that there are items in your answers list. The value of i starts at 0, and increases by 1 each time the loop is run. The first time, it will compare Answers[0] with UserAnswers[0] and determine the source of the image with the id 'markbox0', and then again with 1, and so on.

Hope that helps you.